# image size for object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Is there an optimal size on which to run the object detection networks available in the object detection API? The API seems to accept images of all sizes, but it is unclear to me what type and how the image is being rescaled before feeding to the network.
Could you please clarify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is a script called [preprocessor_builder](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f87a58cd96d45de73c9a8330a06b2ab56749a7fa/research/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py#L201) which is responsible for that. So whenever you feed an image to the network it has to go through this preprocessing and makes sure that the image is resized properly to match the network depending on your network configuration file.

And actual resizing is happening [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f87a58cd96d45de73c9a8330a06b2ab56749a7fa/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py#L1426).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is dependent on which model you're running. For our SSD models, we will reshape the image to 300x300 pixels. For FasterRCNN or RFCN, we'll reshape between 600-1024 pixels.

The images the user should add into the TFRecord can be any size, but we recommend users keep sizes as small as possible (ie. ~400-600px max per dimension for SSD, or ~1500px max per dimension for FasterRCNN or R-FCN) for memory reasons.

Comment: For prediction on a SavedModel, should we first reshape the image or feed it into image_tensor:0 as is? I'm seeing prediction times like 45sec/image on the faster rcnn model. Trying to debug.

Comment: But simple resizing will distort all the input images (some more, some less), won't this negatively affect the detection quality? I've been confused by this for a while and you might be the right guy to ask :)

Comment: What is the best practice for large satellite images e.g. 6000x4000 where you want do continuous feature box identification across the image?